# Is it possible to specify Toast notification sound on Windows Phone 8 before Update 3

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I understand that in Update 3 we can specify custom sounds. But is it possible to specify *any* different sounds before Update 3, other than the default chime? If so, how?

The following is the xml payload I'm sending to the phone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
  <wp:Toast>
    <wp:Text1>WEATHER ALERT</wp:Text1>
    <wp:Text2>asdfasdf</wp:Text2>
    <wp:Param>/Page2.xaml?NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification</wp:Param>
  </wp:Toast>
  <wp:audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM" loop="true" />
</wp:Notification>
```

but regardless of what sound I specify in the line

```
<wp:audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.IM" loop="true" />
```

or

```
<wp:audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm7" loop="true" />
```

it always plays the same sound.

Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible. This feature was introduced with GDR 3.
Reference:

> Windows Phone 8 Update 3 (OS version number 8.0.10492) introduces the ability to provide a custom sound for toast notifications.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_gdr3