# Windows Phone 8.1 .Local Storage file for toast notification

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-phone-8.1, toast

I'm having a trouble with sending a toast for Windows Phone 8.1 with custom sound. I followed MSDN instructions for changing the template of toast notification. I'm trying to record the sound and then, after saving it to local storage, add to XML body of toast. Here's piece of code:

```
            ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
            XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);
            XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(titlebox.Text));
            toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(mainMsgbox.Text));
            IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
            XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");

            if(sound!=null)
                audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appdata:///local/"+sound.Name);
            else
                audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///sounds/Bell.mp3");
            toastNode.AppendChild(audio);
```

Also, I must mention, that I create an audio in *wav* format with *1 second* duration. I have tried such methods as `Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sound.Name)`, `Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Name, sound.Name)` , or just by specifiying `sound.Path` , but no luck. Needless to say, that `ms-appdata:///local/` and `ms-appdata:///` either not working. Any ideas? Does Windows Phone 8.1 can play notification sound from local storage?

**EDIT**: Found this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/25a6dc52-4bbb-41d7-ad14-8dc915edd783/how-to-use-temporary-files-on-tilestoasts?forum=winappswithcsharp . So, the uri `ms-appdata:///` works. But that case was for images. Still no luck with audio files :c

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492193/is-it-possible-to-specify-toast-notification-sound-on-windows-phone-8-before-upd) post, hope this will be fulfils your requirement

Comment: @Vasistan, I checked that MSDN article. But if that supports GRD3, then WP 8.1 will support this as well? But anyway, `audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///sounds/Bell.mp3")` works. Not working only dynamically created sound, which is located in IsolatedStorage. If I provide the audio with the application, I can use custom sound. But if I use sound from the `Application.Current.LocalFolder` , it fails